# I have an error when I try to include the table

Tags: node.js, nestjs, prisma

## I have an error when I try to include the table.

i do

```
findAll() {
    return this.prismaService.services.findMany({
        include: {uploadedFile: true}
    });
}
```

and i get error

```
thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'Expected parent IDs to be set when ordering by parent ID.', query-engine/core/src/interpreter/query_interpreters/inmemory_record_processor.rs:69:18
note: run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display a backtrace
\[Nest\] 163471 - 06/20/2023, 8:27:47 PM ERROR \[ExceptionsHandler\]
Invalid this.prismaService.services.findMany() invocation in
/root/stones/back/src/service/service.service.ts:14:40

11 }
12
13 findAll() {
→ 14 return this.prismaService.services.findMany(
Expected parent IDs to be set when ordering by parent ID.

This is a non-recoverable error which probably happens when the Prisma Query Engine has a panic.

https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?body=Hi+Prisma+Team%21+My+Prisma+Client+just+crashed.+This+is+the+report%3A%0A%23%23+Versions%0A%0A%7C+Name++++++++++++%7C+Version++++++++++++%7C%0A%7C-----------------%7C--------------------%7C%0A%7C+Node++++++++++++%7C+v16.20.0+++++++++++%7C+%0A%7C+OS++++++++++++++%7C+debian-openssl-1.1.x%7C%0A%7C+Prisma+Client+++%7C+4.15.0+++++++++++++%7C%0A%7C+Query+Engine++++%7C+8fbc245156db7124f997f4cecdd8d1219e360944%7C%0A%7C+Database++++++++%7C+mysql++++++++++++++%7C%0A%0A%0A%0A%23%23+Logs%0A%60%60%60%0Aprisma%3AtryLoadEnv+Environment+variables+loaded+from+%2Froot%2Fstones%2Fback%2F.env%0Aprisma%3Aclient+checkPlatformCaching%3Apostinstall+%0Aprisma%3Aclient+checkPlatformCaching%3AciName+%0Aprisma%3AtryLoadEnv+Environment+variables+loaded+from+%2Froot%2Fstones%2Fback%2F.env%0Aprisma%3Aclient+dirname+%2Froot%2Fstones%2Fback%2Fnode_modules%2F.prisma%2Fclient%0Aprisma%3Aclient+relativePath+..%2F..%2F..%2Fprisma%0Aprisma%3Aclient+cwd+%2Froot%2Fstones%2Fback%2Fprisma%0Aprisma%3Aclient+protocol+graphql%0Aprisma%3Aclient+clientVersion+4.15.0%0Aprisma%3Aclient+clientEngineType+library%0Aprisma%3Aclient%3AlibraryEngine+internalSetup%0Aprisma%3Aget-platform+Found+distro+info%3A%0A%7B%0A++%22targetDistro%22%3A+%22debian%22%2C%0A++%22familyDistro%22%3A+%22debian%22%2C%0A++%22originalDistro%22%3A+%22ubuntu%22%0A%7D%0Aprisma%3Aget-platform+Trying+platform-specific+paths+for+%22debian%22+%28and+%22ubuntu%22%29%0Aprisma%3Aget-platform+Found+libssl.so+file+using+platform-specific+paths%3A+libssl.so%0Aprisma%3Aget-platform+The+parsed+libssl+version+is%3A+undefined%0Aprisma%3Aget-platform+Falling+back+to+%22ldconfig%22+and+other+generic+paths%0Aprisma%3Aget-platform+Command+%22ldconfig+-p+%7C+sed+%22s%2F.*%3D%3Es*%2F%2F%22+%7C+sed+%22s%7C.*%2F%7C%7C%22+%7C+grep+libssl+%7C+sort+%7C+grep+-v+%22libssl.so.0%22%22+successfully+returned+%22libssl3.so%0Alibssl.so%0Alibssl.so.1.1%0A%22%0Aprisma%3Aget-platform+Found+libssl.so+file+using+%22ldconfig%22+or+other+generic+paths%3A+libssl3.so%0Alibssl.so%0Alibssl.so.1.1%0A%0Aprisma%3Aget-platform+The+parsed+libssl+version+is%3A+1.1.x%0Aprisma%3Aclient%3Aengines%3AresolveEnginePath+enginePath+%2Froot%2Fstones%2Fback%2Fnode_modules%2F.prisma%2Fclient%2Flibquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x.so.node%0Aprisma%3Aclient%3AlibraryEngine+library+starting%0Aprisma%3Aclient%3AlibraryEngine+library+started%0Aprisma%3Aclient%3AlibraryEngine+sending+request%2C+this.libraryStarted%3A+true%0A%60%60%60%0A%0A%23%23+Client+Snippet%0A%60%60%60ts%0A%2F%2F+PLEASE+FILL+YOUR+CODE+SNIPPET+HERE%0A%60%60%60%0A%0A%23%23+Schema%0A%60%60%60prisma%0A%2F%2F+PLEASE+ADD+YOUR+SCHEMA+HERE+IF+POSSIBLE%0A%60%60%60%0A%0A%23%23+Prisma+Engine+Query%0A%60%60%60%0A%7B%22X%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%0A%60%60%60%0A&title=Expected+parent+IDs+to+be+set+when+ordering+by+parent+ID.&template=bug_report.md


If you want the Prisma team to look into it, please open the link above 
To increase the chance of success, please post your schema and a snippet of
how you used Prisma Client in the issue.
```

try add orderBy but it did not help

```
"prisma": "^3.0.2",
"@prisma/client": "^3.0.2"
```

i'm using database mysql

Comment: Can you please share how you are creating services records?